# How to find PropertyInfo about a DependencyProperty (on a DependencyObject) in WinUI 3

Tags: reflection, dependency-properties, winui-3, propertyinfo

Sometimes it's useful to have more information about a `DependencyProperty` than metadata supplies. For example, in generalized tracing methods and event handlers, it's helpful to be able to find the name (and other characteristics) of a `DependencyProperty` on a `DependencyObject`.

In WinUI 3, `System.Reflection` reports `DependencyProperties` as `MemberType=Properties` so we use `GetProperties()` to get a `PropertyInfo[]` containing information on all properties on an object or type (WPF reports `DependencyProperties` as `MemberType=Fields` so we'd use `GetFields()` instead).

`DependencyProperties` are actually declared as `static` fields and the `Get...` methods in `Reflection` typically default to not listing static members. When calling `GetProperties`, be sure to include the `BindingFlags.Static` flag, as well as `BindingFlags.Public` to include public `DependencyProperties` in your list.

Next, we check each of the returned `PropertyInfo[]` items to see if they are actually about the `DependencyProperty` identifier of interest. If `dp` holds the identifier of your `DependencyProperty` of interest and `pi` is the `PropertyInfo` item you're checking, use the `object.ReferenceEquals(pi.GetValue(sender), dp)` method to see if they both refer to the same identifier (Note: this will be false if `pi` and `dp` are on different objects or identify different properties). There should be one, and only one, match in the returned array.

Here is the beginning of a `PropertyChanged` handler that demonstrates:

```
    private static void BoundPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyProperty dp)
    {
        // sender is DependencyObject upon which the dp changed

        PropertyInfo dpInfo = sender.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
            .Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(DependencyProperty) && object.ReferenceEquals(pi.GetValue(sender), dp)).Single();

        // Trace logic, etc.
    }
```

The first statement has four parts:

1. `sender.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)` fetches information on all properties on sender's type. The `BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy` flag means, essentially, include inherited properties, too.
2. `.Where(pi => pi.PropertyType == typeof(DependencyProperty)` selects only members that have a `PropertyType` of `DependencyProperty` (routed events might be in the list from 1), too).
3. `&& object.ReferenceEquals(pi.GetValue(sender), dp))` further limits the selected items to those that refer to the same identifiers.
4. the `.Single();` clause selects the sole member of the resulting list and throws an error if there is more (or less) than one.

One caveat is that this approach relies heavily on reflection, which is relatively slow.

I don't know of a better way to do this, but I'd welcome suggestions and improvements!

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, from .NET/C# you're only looking at the C# projection created by C#/WinRT (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/). The source is really WinMD files that C#/WinRT uses. You can see them in obj directory when you compile a WinUI3 project (ex: Microsoft.UI.winmd, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.winmd,etc.)

Comment: This looks promising but there don't appear to be any *.winMD files in the project at all. Furthermore, aren't *.winMD files the compiled output of the C#/WinRT components? Any idea where the source for these might be?

Comment: As I said, WinMD are not in the project, they are somewhere in the obj directory once you've compiled. I don't know where the sources are, WinUI3 was supposed to be open source but that promise seems forgotten.

Comment: Thanks very much. I thought you meant the project obj directory!